# Setting Google Cloud Storage access-control-allow-origin header still couldn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, frontend, next.js

After setting cors configuration in my json-file, I still kept getting error response, the following are my configurations and response. Please, your help is needed, I have been battling with this for days.

```
[
   {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type"],
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
   }
]
```

Here is my fetch api:

```
fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketName/photos/608d04ab0d1bd21fb4e94876/02-07-2021/SGNArtboard-1[751].png')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.blob()
    })
    .then(function(blob) {
      console.log('blob : ', blob)
    });
```

Here is my error response:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketName/photos/608d04ab0d1bd21fb4e94876/02-07-2021/SGNArtboard-1[751].png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what happened but all of a sudden it start working properly, but here is my present configuration, just in case...

```
   [
     {
        "origin": ["http://localhost:3000"],
        "responseHeader": ["X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type"],
        "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
      }
   ]
```